# ¿Puedo tratar un emoji como si fuera un solo caracter? Python

Tags: python

el problema que tengo es con los emojis que son compuestos con dos carácteres, por ejemplo: ‍ python lo reconoce como dos:  ‍

Entonces yo tengo varios programas simples, por eso.
Por ejemplo este:

```
x = input("inserte frase:".encode(""))
for i in x:
    if x.count(i)>1:
        print(i)
```

Que hace que si un emoji está repetido me lo muestre. Suponiendo que pongo la siguiente cadena: 1️⃣0️⃣4️⃣▶️4️⃣8️⃣5️⃣9️⃣⏯️▶️⏮️⬅️⬆️⬇️
La salida es la siguiente:
⃣
⃣
4️
⃣
▶
4
⃣
⃣
⃣
⃣

▶
️

O por ejemplo este:

```
x = input("Palabra a componer ")
for i in range(len(x) + 1):
    fin=x[0:i]
    if len(fin)>0:
        if fin[-1]== " ":
            hi=0
        else:
            print(fin)
```

Que hace un desglose de una cadena de texto. Cuando pongo esto: 1️⃣0️⃣
La salida es la siguiente:

```
1
1️
1️⃣
1️⃣0
1️⃣0️
1️⃣0️⃣
1️⃣0️⃣
```

Cuando debería de ser:

```
1️⃣
1️⃣0️⃣
1️⃣0️⃣
```

Lo que quiero es que ese tipo de emojis compuestos los trate como si fuera uno solo ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Comment: Python utiliza nativamente _unicode_ para codificar todas las cadenas de texto. Para interactuar con el medio, se emplea alguna codificación de caracteres que tu sistema operativo pueda entender, siendo la codificación UTF-8 la más habitual. En esta codificación un carácter se puede codificar en 1, 2 ó 4 bytes, pero en python se sigue tratando como un único caracter unicode. Dicho lo cual, es tu sistema operativo quien distingue uno o dos emojis, no python.

Comment: He estado investigando porque me intereso la  pregunta , he podido ver que el ```emoji``` para poder  visualizarse utiliza 4 distintos códigos ```unicode``` que son estos ```U+1F469 U+1F3FB U+200D U+1F9B0``` , he intentado concatenarlo pero no he llegado a poder visualizarlo, igual te envió el link como referencia: https://hotemoji.com/1-woman-red-hair-emoji.html

Answer (score 1):

Existe el paquete `grapheme`, que hace justo lo que pides (primero debes instalarlo, no es estándar).

```
>>> import grapheme
>>> cadena = "Hola! ‍" 
>>> grapheme.length(cadena)
7
```

De la documentación de `grapheme`:

> Las cadenas Unicode están compuestas por una serie de caracteres
> Unicode, pero un carácter Unicode no siempre se corresponde con un
> carácter percibido por el usuario. Algunos caracteres percibidos por
> los humanos se representan como dos o más caracteres Unicode.
>
> Sin embargo, todas las funciones de cadenas de Python y los métodos
> de cadenas funcionan con caracteres Unicode individuales sin tener
> en cuenta su conexión entre sí.
>
> Esta biblioteca implementa las reglas por defecto de unicode para
> grupos de grafemas extendidos, y proporciona un conjunto de funciones
> para la manipulación de cadenas basadas en grafemas.

Para mayor información, puedes darte una leída a https://hsivonen.fi/string-length/ y https://github.com/alvinlindstam/grapheme